# Is it illegal to download data from a misconfigured server that is open to the public?

Tags: united-states, internet

Bob has a website that he hosts online and is open to the public. A portion of the site has "members only" data. However, Bob implemented his security protection of this sensitive data incorrectly. So when Alice clicks the link to view the protected data, instead of being prompted to login or sign up. She just gets access to the data.

Has Alice broken the law if she unintentionally views/downloads the members only data?

Comment: The link itself, is it already visible/clickable by everybody? Or does someone need to assemble the link before it can be followed?

Comment: @Greendrake Its clickable by everybody but the function that triggers the security mechanisms is broken/missing.

Comment: So what _should_ happen is that I click on the button and get shown a login screen and after login I see the material. The login screen would tell me that I’m unauthorised AND stop me from viewing. If I could hack my way in I would still be unauthorised. But the login screen isn’t shown and I can view the documents.

Comment: It is absolutely critical that Alice did not realize the data was supposed to be members only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most apparent potential offences would be under [18 U.S.C. § 1030](https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=(title:18%20section:1030%20edition:prelim)), but these require the [*mens rea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mens_rea) of "knowingly" or "intentionally" doing things without authorization, or doing so "with intent to defraud", etc. See also the Department of Justice's [manual entry](https://www.justice.gov/jm/jm-9-48000-computer-fraud) on this family of offences. Particularly relevant is this quote:

> As part of proving that the defendant acted knowingly or intentionally, the attorney for the government must be prepared to **prove that the defendant was aware of the facts that made the defendant’s access unauthorized at the time of the defendant’s conduct**.

Given your stipulation that the person has *unintentionally* viewed or downloaded the material without authorization, this would not be a violation of 18 U.S.C. § 1030.

Comment: I think the person did intentionally view the material, but due to the website design and broken software they had no suspicion at all and couldn’t have any suspicion that someone didn’t want them to.

Comment: There is US case law to the effect that "knowingly" has narrow scope, eg "knowing to be false in a federal matter" is about knowing to be false, and not knowing to be federal.

Comment: The answer would be the same in England and Wales - and it doesn't seem worth adding a whole new answer just to same "same".